# Understanding a bit operation

Tags: java, int, bit

Trying to understand this one line of code:

```
int solution_mask |= 1 << (1+ solution.charAt(i) - 'A');
```

lets say that solution.charAt(i) is 122. So 122-65 = 57.

1+ 57 = 58

**How does 1 get shifted 58 bits to the left in solution_mask, i.e. how does solution_mask variable store the value 58?**

Here's the complete code for context:

```
 public static int[][] find(String guess, String soln) {

 int[][] res={0,0};
 int solution_mask = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
 solution_mask |= 1 << (1 + solution.charAt(i) - ‘A’);
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
 if (guess.charAt(i) == solution.charAt(i)) {
 res[0]++;
 } else if ((solution_mask &
 (1 << (1 + guess.charAt(i) - ‘A’))) >= 1) {
 res[1]++;
 }
 }
 return res;
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps `solution` is expected to contain only upper case letters.

Comment: Your line of code doesn't compile.

Comment: @mikea Presumably the line was `solution_mask |= 1 << (1+ solution.charAt(i) - 'A');` and the OP added the `int` to indicate the type, not realising it would be invalid.

Comment: folks, i meant to indicate the type of solution_mask, this line clearly isn't meant to compile. you would have to set up other things for it like String solution,etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Java shifts are modded by 32 (or 64, for longs) before they're applied.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995773/2056153)

That means `1 << 58` is equivalent to `1 << (58 % 32)` which is `1 << 26`

Comment: Thanks, just a minor correction, acc to to the code I am putting it at position 27 (1+58)%32...i.e. (59%32). I'm wondering if I can just do away with the '1+..'. It does not seem to be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code should be something like:

```
int solution_mask = 0;
...
for ( int i = 0; i < solution.length(); i++ ) {
  solution_mask |= 1 << (1+ solution.charAt(i) - 'A');
}
```

Then this is setting one bit in the `solution_mask` for each character in the `solution` string. The result will therefor be a bit pattern indicating which characters are present in the solution.

E.G. If the `solution` string is "ABDF" the `solution_mask` will be (in binary) `1010110`.

If `solution` contains any characetrs beyond `A..Z[\]^_` and strange things will happen because an `int` is only 32bits wide.

Comment: I thought the same as you too but then I tried running for string YRGZ and RGGz, still got the correct answer.